# Promise either never get called, or is rejected (Parse JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-server

I am trying to write a function that add or edit some fields on a User object.

The problem come when I try to save the user, if I use `user.save`, the Promise is rejected with error 206 `UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError`.

However, if I get the session id (and documentation about that is scarce), the promise never get resolve, nor rejected. The app seems to just jump to the callback.

My function:

```
function update(user, callback) {
    let query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    query.equalTo("username", user.email);
    query.find().then(
        (users) => {
            if(users.length === 0) {
                callback('Non existent user');
            } else {
                let user = users[0];

                // user.set('some', 'thing');
                console.log('save');
                user.save(/*{
                    sessionToken: user.getSessionToken()
                }*/).then(
                    (test) => {
                        console.log('OK - ' + test);
                        callback();
                    }, (err) => {
                        console.log('ERR- ' + require('util').inspect(err));
                        // console.log(callback.toString());
                        callback(error.message);
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        (error) => {
            callback(error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

Called with:

```
var async = require('async'),
    baas = require('./baas.js');

async.waterfall([
    (callback) => {
        callback(null, {
            email: 'user@test.com',
            password: 'password'
        });
    },
    (user, callback) => {
        console.log('connect');
        baas.connect(() => { //Initialize the connection to Parse, and declare use of masterKey
            callback(null, user);
        });
    },
    (user, callback) => {
        console.log('update');
        baas.update(user, (err) => {
            callback(err);
        });
    }
], (err) => {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
});
```

The logs become:
Without session token:

```
connect
update
save
ERR- ParseError { code: 206, message: 'cannot modify user sA20iPbC1i' }
```

With session token:

```
connect
update
save
```

I do not understand how it is possible that the promise just callback without printing anything, nor why no error are raised anywhere.

Edit:

Following @user866762 advice, I tried to replace the query with `Parse.User.logIn` and use the resulting `User` object.

While this solution give me a `sessionToken`, the end result is the same, parse crash if I don t provide the session token, or give me a error if I do.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(user.getSessionToken())` before you `console.log('save')`?

Comment: @user866762: Should have think of it earlier, it print `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Parse Dev guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-security-for-user-objects):

> ...you are not able to invoke any of the `save` or `delete` methods unless the `Parse.User` was obtained using an authenticated method, like `logIn` or `signUp`.

You might also try [becoming](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.User.html#methods_become) the user before saving, but I have my doubts that will work.

When you're "get[ting] the session id" my guess is that you're really breaking something. Either Parse is having a heart attack at you asking for the session token, or when you're passing it in `save` you're causing something there to explode.

Comment: Becoming the user would be a bad idea, and keeping the password to be able to `logIn` in this function is not something I like, but I ll try that.

Comment: After trying, I get the same error as when I don't provide a user token. However, I can obtain the `sessionToken`, but we go back to the same error than before, parse crash and don t call the promise.